# Importing Bibliography in Xetex

Tags: bibliographies, xetex

As you found out I am relatively new to XeTeX and I want to import bibliography to my academic essay. But I have a few questions on how to do that:

1. Should I record Bibliography in separate file or define it on the same tex file?
2. If I define it over a separate file, how XeTeX will find out the bibliographic references?

Comment: Your queries do not appear to be Xe(La)TeX-specific -- they pertain to pdf(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX as well. Regarding your first question: Yes, you should place the bibliographic entries (in bib format) in a separate file (with extension `.bib`). Regarding your second question: Please familiarize yourself with the basics of creating bibliographies using either BibTeX or `biblatex`.

Comment: Have a look at all of https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management to find out about the different methods for bibliographies in TeX.